# Android - Download Webpage With Images and VIDEOS

Tags: android, html, api, kotlin, webview

I’m Having Trouble finding the best solution to design a signage app, which includes downloading a specific web page with all content (html, css, js, images, videos) sent from the server using an API, to a local folder on the device, and then load this website in a webview for offline use.

is there any solution for that ?
Thanks

Comment: `Having Trouble finding the best solution`. So you know some solutions already. Which ones?

Comment: oh my bad, "Finding a Solution" @blackapps